# How to add two tensors with different shapes in python or tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have two different shapes of tensors generated by two models. when I print them it's like below

```
caption loss is (2, 128)
image loss is (128, 128)
```

One tensor shape is `(2, 128)` and the other one shape is `(128, 128)`. The code part of these two models is below

```
captions_loss = keras.losses.kl_divergence(
        y_true=targets, y_pred=logits, #from_logits=True
    )

images_loss = keras.losses.kl_divergence(
        y_true=tf.transpose(targets), y_pred=tf.transpose(logits), #from_logits=True
    )
```

When I add these two like below then it throws an error.

```
return (captions_loss + images_loss) / 2
```

Is there any solution to add these two

```
captions_loss = (2, 128)
images_loss = (128, 128)
```

Comment: What's the resu,t supposed to be? Shape, dtype?  Do the calculation iterativelyif it helps clarify the desired action.

Comment: Sir, It returns the mean of the loss over the batch. The desired output should be something 2d matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tensors are generally also broadcastable. You can try a few options and see how they affect model performance:

```
import tensorflow as tf

captions_loss =  tf.random.normal((2, 128))
images_loss = tf.random.normal((128, 128))

# Option 1:
(tf.reduce_sum(captions_loss, axis=0) + images_loss) / 2

# Option 2:
(tf.reduce_mean(captions_loss, axis=0) + images_loss) / 2

# Option 3:
(captions_loss[0, :] + images_loss + captions_loss[1, :]) / 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you convert your matrices to numpy-arrays, you can take advantage of numpys [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/1.20/user/theory.broadcasting.html) to compatible shapes:

```
import numpy as np


A = np.array([
    [10, 10, 10]
])

B = np.array([
    [2, 2, 2],
    [3, 3, 3],
    [1, 1, 1],
])

print(A.shape)
print(B.shape)
print(A + B)
```

Output:

```
(1, 3)
(3, 3)
[[12 12 12]
 [13 13 13]
 [11 11 11]]
```

Comment: I do something like this `c = captions_loss.numpy()`
        `d = images_loss.numpy()`
        `return (c + d) / 2` but it generates error that `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,128) (128,128) `.